# Unity - Very dark mesh when static lighting is disabled

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a door in Unity with realtime lighting. The door will move so I disabled static lighting but it becomes very dark. The door should have the same color as the white frame around it. If I enable static lighting on it, it becomes white like the frame but then its lighting is not updated when it moves.

Here is the door and its white frame which have the same material applied.

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume all your lights are static.

To have non static Objects be illuminated you need also a non-static light sources.

Also your Ambient light is set (nearly?) to black so that seems to be currently all light which is available for the door.